# iPhone graphics work on Simulator not on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

I am writing an app using tiled to do my levels. The app works fine in the simulator but when I run it on the device all the sprites on the level are pushed into the bottom left corner. The map is not distorted at all and is the same place, only the sprites are distorted. I have checked the file names and they match up fine. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: What device are you running on? Perhaps the simulator is in non-retina and the device is retina?

Comment: I agree, sounds very much like running on a Retina device without providing -hd assets. Disable retina mode in cocos2d director or add -hd retina resolution assets.

Comment: i am currently running on a 4s

Comment: okay thanks. i realized I was running the normal simulator and my phone has retina display

Comment: how can i disable retina mode?

Comment: Retina display is disabled by default in the cocos2d templates. Do you mean enable retina display on the iphone?

Comment: [[CCDirector sharedDirector] enableRetinaDisplay:NO];

Answer (score 0):

If you you do not support retina displays, You have to disable retina support. To do it, go to AppDelegate.m file find a line that looks like this:

```
if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```

and change it with this one:

```
[director_ enableRetinaDisplay:NO]
```

Comment: This is a big no-no if you plan to publish on the AppStore though - Apple now doesn't approve apps that don't support Retina display and/or iPhone 5 display natively.

Comment: Agree. But for testing the app or if author just plays around, that solution may be fine.